# Find array element by key in a chain

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using an underscore chain, and am stuck on the last bit of it.

I simply need it to look at a array of objects and return the correct object by it's key. here's what I have

```
var item = _.chain(items)
 .findwhere({module: modulename})
 .result('customUrl') 
 //here is where the problem is
 .find(function(v,k){ return k == stateName })
 .value();
```

So this works find up until that .find . At that point in the object, the find is looking at something this:

```
 [{"obj1" : ["1","2"]},{"obj2" : ["3","4"]}]
```

I just want it to return the one with the same key that is stored in that variable stateName that is being passed. So if stateName was "obj1", it would return me ["1","2"]. If there is a better way to do it without underscore, I'm all ears, but I've been using it for now.

Thanks

Edit: I've made an attempt based on the answers here.

Just to be clear this is what my data looks like :

```
[
 {"module":"module1",
   "customUrl":[{"mod1":["1","2"]},{"mod2":["1","2"]}]
 },
 {"module":"module2",
  "customUrl":[{"mod3":["true","false"]},{"mod4":["5","6"]}]
 }
]
```

And the attempt :

```
 checkitem = _.chain(currentState)
                    .findWhere({module: moduleName})
                    .result('customUrl')
                    .find(function(v){ return v.hasOwnProperty(stateName)})
                    .values()
                    .flatten()
                    .value();
```

So if the var stateName is mod1, I would like it to return me ["1","2"], like in the answers below, I think something is wrong in my chaining though. Thanks!

Comment: What if there are multiple matches?

Comment: I can be certain there will not in this case @thefourtheye

Comment: @thefourtheye: `find()` returns the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that there will be only one match, then you can use `find`, because it will return after getting the first match.

```
var items = [{
    "obj1": ["1", "2"]
}, {
    "obj2": ["3", "4"]
}, {
    "obj3": ["5", "6"]
}];

var stateName = "obj1";

var item = _.chain(items)
    .find(function(currentObject) {
        return _.has(currentObject, stateName);
    })
    .values()
    .flatten()
    .value();

console.log(item);
# [ '1', '2' ]
```

1. In the [`find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) function, we return `true` only if the current object being processed has a property with the name in the `stateName`, with the [`_.has`](http://underscorejs.org/#has) function. At this point the result will be like this

   ```
   { obj1: [ '1', '2' ] }
   ```
2. If that is true, then only that object will be returned. Since you need only the values, we call the [`values`](http://underscorejs.org/#values) function on it. At this point, the result will be like this

   ```
   [ [ '1', '2' ] ]
   ```
3. And then `values` actually returns an array of values. So, we flatten it with [`flatten`](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) function to get the actual value. And here, the final result would be

   ```
   [ '1', '2' ]
   ```

Comment: This seems to be the right way, however i cannot get it to work in a chain with what I have, I updated my question. Thanks again!

Comment: @a It works fine for me. Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/81hvjg7v/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` to see if a property exists (which becomes your predicate):

```
var item = _.chain(items)
 .findwhere({module: modulename})
 .result('customUrl')
 .find(function(v){ return stateName in v })
 .value();
```

Alternatively:

```
 .find(function(v){ return v.hasOwnProperty(stateName) })
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use filter instead of find?

```
.filter(function(v, k) {
    return k === stateName;
});
```

Comment: because i'm trying to find by just the key, not the values